# Best Hosted Mail Server for a SaaS Web App?

Tags: email, hosting, email-server, web-applications

I'm developing a CRM SaaS based web application, and one of the features i would like to have is the ability for users to foward emails to my app.
The app will also from time to time send out notification emails.

Other than setting up my own mail server, does anyone know of any **hosted email servers/services** which would allow me to do this?

One of the requirements is that it should have unlimited incoming mails, and if there is any limit on the outgoing, it should be reasonably high.

*PS: Also if host has a good API for managing mailboxes that would be a hugh plus*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rackspace email has an API, "unlimited" has different meanings, you get the storage you pay for, per mb is very cheap if you get a reseller account.